# Any way to write a text file and have it replace the previous one?

Tags: javascript, html, text-files

I have some javascript that I use to write a text file when the user leaves the page.  Here is the function:

```
function handleBrowserCloseButton() { 

get_text();   

var textToWrite = array;
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
var fileNameToSaveAs = "windows.txt"

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
downloadLink.click();
}
```

This works well.  The only problem is the name of the file is constant - "windows.txt".  What this means is that every time the user leaves the page the file written is "windows(n).txt" where n increases in value by one each time.

Is there a way to have javascript replace the file "windows.txt" instead of creating a new file each time?

Comment: how are you saving it?

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: could I erase the previous version first to achieve the desired result?

Comment: No.  You have no access to the user's disk.

Comment: If your data is small you could just store your data in `localStorage` it gives you about 5MB worth of space to save `string` data

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into this.  Where is the data stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you are using browser's JavaScript, for security reasons, you can not change the existed files on your local machine.

But you may try to use `localStorage` if the file is not too big.

```
 // Store
 localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

 // Retrieve
 localStorage.getItem("key");
```

About the size of `localStorage`:
[What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

The key-value pairs in localStorage will be stored in browsers and according to the implementations of each browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the helpful comment of Patrick Evans, I switched from trying to write out a local text file to storing the data in localStorage.